# Proof of induction - find closed formula for recurrence

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

So I have a question below that asks to find a closed-form formula for the following set and then prove it using induction. I'm pretty sure my formula is correct but I'm struggling to prove it.

1) Consider the function $f:\Bbb N^+→\Bbb N$ defined by:

$$
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
 1&\text{if}\, n∈ {1,2,3}\\
 4f(n-3)&\text{if}\, n> 3\\
\end{cases}
$$

Write a closed form formula for $f(n)$ and prove that your formula is correct.

So I did:

$$f(1) = 1$$

$$f(2) = 1$$

$$f(3) = 1$$

$$f(4) = 4 * f(1) = 4 * 1 = 4$$

$$f(5) = 4 * f(2) = 4 * 1 = 4$$

$$f(6) = 4 * f(3) = 4 * 1 = 4$$

$$f(7) = 4 * f(4) = 4 * 4 = 16$$

$$f(7) = 4 * f(5) = 4 * 4 = 16$$

$$f(8) = 4 * f(6) = 4 * 4 = 16$$

and so on.

I believe the formula would be represented with the floor function as $4\left[\frac{(n - 1)}{3}\right]$. The issue is when I try to do my base case and proof of induction, my values don't seem to match.

Base case: $n = 1$

$$f(1) =  4\left[\frac{(1 - 1)}{3}\right].$$

$f(1) = 0$ which isn't right because it was stated that $f(1) = 1$ above.

When I try to prove it:

$$f(n-1) = 4f(n-3)$$

$$f(n-1) = 4*\left(4\left\lfloor\frac{(n - 1)}{3}\right\rfloor\right)$$

$$f(n-1) = 4*\left(4\left(\left\lfloor\frac{(n - 1 - 1)}{3}\right\rfloor\right)\right)$$

$$f(n-1) = 4*\left(4\left(\left\lfloor\frac{(n - 2)}{3}\right\rfloor\right)\right)$$

Which causes me to be stuck. I can't seem to properly evaluate the function to $4\left[\frac{(n - 1)}{3}\right]$.

Comment: When the base cases don't match the formula you guessed, then your guess was wrong.

Comment: Hint: $1\equiv 4^0, 4\equiv 4^1, 16\equiv 4^2,\cdots$. So, perhaps you need to play with the _powers_ of $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since you multiply by $4$ every thrid value, your variable $n$ should be in the exponent.
$$f(n)=4^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{3}\right\rfloor}$$